# Reproducing a published image in ggplot : stacked barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to reproduce this image in ggplot:

[image]

*Figure 2b, from Zak et al., 2016*.  see - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5392204/

I initially tried to use a stacked bar plot, but I cannot get the bins to be all the same width.  It seems the underlying nature of bar plots makes each category a set size which cannot be modified.

I set the x-axis as the timepoint, the y-axis as each sample and the colour with the value.

I have created a connected line plot with some success; however, I don’t think it has the same sharpness seen in the image there.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I can recreate this in ggplot using a stacked barplot with custom heights? Or should I just keep trying to improve the line chart?

```
Code : ## Connecting Line chart  
 ggplot(groupC, aes(colour=value, y=sample, x=timepoint)) + 
  geom_line(size=12)  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=12)) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100), limits=c(1, 80), na.value = NA, name="Value") +
  ylab("")  +
  theme_classic()

## Bar Chart    
ggplot(groupC_bar, aes(x=sample, y=timepoint, fill=value)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black")  +   coord_flip() 

Data
sample  timepoint   value
a1  m0  0
b2  m0  2
c3  m0  6
d4  m0  7
e5  m0  3
a1  m2  9
b2  m2  10
c3  m2  12
d4  m2  16
e5  m2  11
a1  m4  16
b2  m4  20
c3  m4  15
d4  m4  20
e5  m4  32
a1  m6  34
b2  m6  34
c3  m6  18
d4  m6  33
e5  m6  54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give the appearance of a gradient fill like this, just flip the co-ordinates and stack the bars, using a custom color palette in the fill aesthetic:

```
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "#DDDD00", "forestgreen"))

df <- data.frame(sample = rep(paste0(letters[1:5], 1:5), each = 100),
                 value  = rep(c(1, 0.8, 0.65, 1.3, 0.5), each = 100),
                 color =  factor(rep(my_palette(100), 5), my_palette(100)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = sample, y = value, fill = color)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Your own data isn't sufficiently gradiated to allow this. You could either interpolate it or have larger blocks of color fill like this:

```r
ggplot(groupC, aes(x = sample, y = value, fill = timepoint)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_palette(4)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

An option with even bin widths:

```
ggplot(groupC, aes(x = 1, y = sample, fill = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("forestgreen", "yellow", "red")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4 - 0.5, labels = unique(groupC$timepoint)) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "timepoint")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I put up an example as I didn’t want to post large data.  I’ve tried it on my data, and it is still not right, maybe I am not clear.  

I want the value variable to be the coloured values and the sample(Y) the time points(X).  I have 14 samples * 8-time points.  If I try the 2nd example, I can’t easily see changed values and the width of the bin depends on the number in value.  Is there any way to have a fixed width for timepoint and the values providing the colour?  I can’t seem to find it even changing the code around?

Comment: Yes!  Oh, wow, that is perfect.  I never knew you could do the breaks like that.  When I tried it, in different ways, it just didn't work out.  Thanks so much, Allan.  I don't want to tell you how have many wasted hours I spent on this today.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, with x=1, is there any way to label the chart?  for example the boxes with their values.  
this isn't important.  I am just trying to make sure I full understand so I can reproduce this on different data in the future.

Comment: @lmrogers34 yes. You should be able to specify `geom_text` with `position = "fill"` to get labels in the middle of the boxes. The position is by default set to stack, so the x = 1 just allows for stacking of boxes one unit at a time, giving them all the same width. You might also want to check out plotting `geom_tile(aes(x = timepoint, y = sample, fill = value))` which makes it even easier to get a similar plot (though without the spaces in between "bars"

Comment: Perfect.  I used : geom_text(aes(label=value), colour="black", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) 

And that works well.  I will mess around with the geom_tile() and see what I can come up with.  Thanks again for your clear code and help.